# SQlite onUpgrade

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting an error with my onUpgrade functions for my Android database. The problem is I alter a table in one version to add new columns, and in a later update function I query that table. If the updates go back to back from an older version, it errors out when I try to access a column from the cursor in the new table. If I run the updates separately, updating from one version at a time, it works just fine. How can I fix this?

The error I get is java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed

This is how I create the new table.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE assignment_settings_temp("+
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                "class_id INTEGER NOT NULL, "+
                "total_weight REAL)");
```

This is where my code errors at.

```
obj.put("id", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
```

I tried adding this after creating the table

```
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
db.beginTransaction();
```

but it still errors out. The difference now though is the new table is in the database afterwards. So I still have the problem that for some reason the cursor says the column does not exist.

Comment: Please include relevant SQLite helper code in the question.

Comment: The code it pretty long, that's why I did not include it. It works just fine if it is only upgraded one version at a time, so I know my code works. The problem is something to do with the onUpgrade not posting changes I guess until it finishes the update.

Comment: Yes, `onUpgrade()` runs inside a transaction and the transaction is not completed until you return from `onUpgrade()`. That's a likely reason. But do include relevant parts of the upgrade code so the question becomes specific and answerable.

Comment: I added the code segments.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the database version number. As I know if you want to call onUpgrade method, you have to change the database version number and alter the table like this

```
db.execSQL("alter table " + TABLE_NAME + " add column sample_column text");
```

Comment: I am not simply altering the table. I used a lot of bad practices when I originally created this table, and now I am cleaning the database up. I had to create a temporary table, transfer the old data to it (modifying it as I do), remove the previous table, and then rename it. Yes, I did change the version number. As I said above, it works just fine if I upgrade it one version at a time. The problem is when the upgrades go back to back.